# cos nx from cos x in fractional form

Tags: trigonometry

I am given $\cos x$ in fractional form. How to find $\cos nx$ in fractional form?

I tried using half angle formula repeatedly, but the extra $x$ introduced a sin x, which might not be rational.

I can't directly find out $x$, as I will lose precision when finding $\cos nx$.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: You are on the wrong tracks by thinking to half angle formulas. Use recurrence formula $\cos((n+1)x)=2 \cos(x) \cos(nx) - \cos((n-1)x)$. Begin by $n=1$, which gives you $\cos(2x)=2 \cos(x)^2-1$, etc...

Comment: What do you call "fractional form" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Chebyshev's polynomials; $\cos nx$ is a polynomial in $\cos x$: $T_n(cos x)$. One shows the polynomial has leading term $2^{n-1}t^n$, and it can be calculated recursively with the second-order recurrence:
$$T_{n+1}(t)=2t T_n(t)-T_{n-1}(t).$$
(deduced from the factorisation formula:$$\cos (n+1)x+\cos (n-1)x=2\cos(nx)\cos x.)$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You can use [Viete's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine,_cosine,_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles)

$$\cos(n\theta) = \sum_{k\text{ even}} (-1)^\frac{k}{2} {n \choose k}\cos^{n-k} \theta \sin^k \theta$$

Comment: LOL. I'd like to see you trying that with $n=10^9$, say (it's for a programming contest, they aim at big numbers).